# CorePlot : Allow horizontal scrolling in positive quadrant only

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-plot

I am working on an iOS application, in which i require to show a scatter plot, but i need to restrict the scrolling along x axis, that too only in positive quadrant.

I have the working graph.
I am using core-plot 1.3.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Regards,
Ishan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the plot to stay within a defined range, use the `globalXRange`. If there is no upper bound, use a plot space delegate to monitor changes to the plot ranges and veto any changes that go outside the desired area.